# What is the correct property name to notify when binding to an element in an Observable collection directly?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a binding of the following form in XAML,

```
Title="{Binding SelectedNewsItems[0].Title}"
```

Note that it refers to a particular element in the `SelectedNewsItems` which is an `ObservableCollection`. (I have a collection of nine buttons of various sizes, each styled, and sized differently and so a more standard `ListView` is not appropriate.)

When I reassign `SelectedNewsItems` I raise a `PropertyChanged` event for `SelectedNewsItems`, however, this does not appear to cause the bindings to update for the individual bound elements and their properties. I have tried the following,

```
public ObservableCollection<NewsItem> _selectedNewsItems;
        public ObservableCollection<NewsItem> SelectedNewsItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this._selectedNewsItems;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._selectedNewsItems != value)
                {
                    this._selectedNewsItems = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    for (int i = 0; i < this._selectedNewsItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Format("SelectedNewsItems[{0}].Content", i));
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Format("SelectedNewsItems[{0}].Title", i));
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Format("SelectedNewsItems[{0}].Id", i));
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Format("SelectedNewsItems[{0}].Image", i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It should be sufficient to just call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedNewsItems");` (at least it works for me).

Comment: Moreover, (afaik) there will never be compound property names in a PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I cannot exacly say where your code is wrong (as I see only part of it), but maybe you haven't set your DataContex or something else. For the purpose of research I've made simple example, which works quite fine. Take a look at it and maybe it will help you:
In Xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="first" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding SelectedNewsItems[0].Name}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Button x:Name="second" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding SelectedNewsItems[1].Name}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

In code behind (I put all the code - yeah quite a lot of, but I cannot guess what is wrong with your code):

```
public class NewsItem
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaiseProperty(string property = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<NewsItem> _selectedNewsItems = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<NewsItem> SelectedNewsItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedNewsItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._selectedNewsItems != value)
            {
                this._selectedNewsItems = value;
                this.RaiseProperty();
                for (int i = 0; i < this._selectedNewsItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.RaiseProperty(String.Format("SelectedNewsItems[{0}].Name", i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        NewsItem firstT = new NewsItem() { Name = "First" };
        NewsItem secondT = new NewsItem() { Name = "Second" };
        SelectedNewsItems.Add(firstT);
        SelectedNewsItems.Add(secondT);

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
        first.Click += first_Click;
        second.Click += second_Click;
    }

    private void first_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewsItem change = new NewsItem() { Name = "Changed by First" };
        SelectedNewsItems[1] = change;
    }

    private void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewsItem change = new NewsItem() { Name = "Changed by Second" };
        SelectedNewsItems[0] = change;
    }
}
```

As I click on buttons the bindigs work, so maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, my code started to work for some other reason which I'm not 100% clear about. In any case it updates with an `ObservableCollection` and `PropertyChanged` event fired when the `ObservableCollection` is replaced. (i.e. the for looop was not necessary).